# Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError with Graph API on .PatchAsync(user)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, microsoft-graph-api

Not quite sure how to solve this error because it isn't specific when I catch the error message

```
Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.ThrowIfFailedResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, Activity activityForAttributes)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendAsync[ModelType](RequestInformation requestInfo, ParsableFactory`1 factory, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendAsync[ModelType](RequestInformation requestInfo, ParsableFactory`1 factory, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.UserItemRequestBuilder.PatchAsync(User body, Action`1 requestConfiguration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

It specifically errors out on this line:

```
await graphClient.Users[$"{id}"].PatchAsync(user);
```

For more context, I am trying to update a users onPremisesExtensionAttributes

In another method elsewhere I create them like this

```
var user = new User
{
    OnPremisesExtensionAttributes = new OnPremisesExtensionAttributes
    {
        ExtensionAttribute1 = "123"
        ExtensionAttribute2 = "abc"
    }
};
```

Everything is correct according to the Microsoft documentation. I am not quite sure how to proceed with this one, I have spent 2 hours reading about it but nothing has fixed it. It was working up until I was tasked to revisit this project and update all dependencies. According to documentation though, this is how you are supposed to patch a user with Graph SDK v5

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Use **try-catch** method in your code to know the exact OData error by including code from [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#error-handling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I ran below code by including **try-catch** method, I got **same error** with `Insufficient privileges` in console like this:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var user = new User
{
    OnPremisesExtensionAttributes = new OnPremisesExtensionAttributes
    {
        ExtensionAttribute1 = "123",
        ExtensionAttribute2 = "abc"
    }
};

try
{
    await graphClient.Users["b3235d2e-19bc-4b2b-a8ef-xxxxxxx"].PatchAsync(user);
    Console.WriteLine("Extension attributes updated successfully");
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
    throw;
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, I added **`User.ReadWrite.All`** permission of **Application** type in application by granting admin consent:

[image]

When I ran the same code again now, I got the **response** successfully like this:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var user = new User
{
    OnPremisesExtensionAttributes = new OnPremisesExtensionAttributes
    {
        ExtensionAttribute1 = "123",
        ExtensionAttribute2 = "abc"
    }
};

try
{
    await graphClient.Users["b3235d2e-19bc-4b2b-a8ef-xxxxxxx"].PatchAsync(user);
    Console.WriteLine("Extension attributes updated successfully");
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
    throw;
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where user's extension attributes are **updated** like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, catching OData actually gave me the correct error code and it was indeed a permission issue. I am still having a bit of an issue with permissions because I am using VisualStudioCredential and trying to make those changes in a test domain. The weird thing is, I granted the correct account permissions to make these changes, but for some reason it still doesn't work. The joy of visiting a project that hasn't been worked in for many months I guess!