# Exception types from az cli commands

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cli

I got a C# code which invokes an az cli command : `"az ad group member add ..."`

How can I know which types of exceptions can be thrown from that command? Specifically, I need the type of the exception when trying to add a user which is already in the group, but I would like to know in general where can I find documentation of possible exceptions from az commands.

This is the documentation of the command which doesn't specify possible exceptions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/group/member?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-group-member-add

Comment: Note that, `az ad group member add ...` will run Microsoft Graph API in the backend and displays **error message** of API response as exception. There is no specific documentation of possible exceptions from az commands. But you can find document on possible error responses of Microsoft Graph here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In general, Azure CLI commands can throw exceptions related to authentication, authorization, network connectivity, and other issues like invalid parameters depending on that specific context/scenario.
>
> Currently, there is **no specific** documentation of possible exceptions
> from az commands. You need to **explicitly** check the error message

In my case, I tried to execute the command with a user who is already in the group to find what type of exception is thrown.

I have one Azure AD group named **`SriGroup`** with below group members:

[image]

When I tried to add user who is already in group using Azure CLI command, I got **exception** as *One or more added object references already exist for the following modified properties: 'members'*

```
az ad group member add --group "SriGroup" --member-id "8710bd50-78b7-45b0-9d43-xxxxxx"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran below Microsoft Graph query that is **equivalent** to above command, I got **same error**:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/groupId/members/$ref/
{
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/userobjId"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can also run the command by adding `--verbose` at the end to know what API it is calling in backend:

```
az ad group member add --group "SriGroup" --member-id "8710bd50-78b7-45b0-9d43-xxxxxx" --verbose
```

**Reference:**
[Microsoft Graph error responses and resource types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors)

Comment: If its of the general type Exception, does it mean I need to actually parse the string message of the exception to determine the specific error?

Comment: Are you not getting any specific error message in your c# code as in az cli command? Determining that **specific error** depends on package you are using in your c# code.

Comment: If you are getting OData error, you need to use **try-catch** block in your c# code to know the exact error. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77119726/microsoft-graph-models-odataerrors-odataerror-with-graph-api-on-patchasyncuser/77120573#77120573

Comment: I do get the same error message in the code as you got in your example. So the question is if to determine that the error was caused due to an existing member and not because of something else, the only way is actually checking that the error message I got is "One or more added object references already exist for the following modified properties: 'members'" ? Because I want to avoid that and that's why I was asking originally about exception type expecting there will be an exception like AlreadyExisitingException or something like that

Comment: Yes, the only way is actually checking that the error message "One or more added object references already exist for the following modified properties: 'members'"

Comment: AFAIK, currently there is no documentation available with all existing exceptions caused with Az cli commands.

Comment: Could you add it to the answer for others in the future that they need to explicitly check the error message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255738/discussion-between-sridevi-and-codemonkey).